# issue with doc.ouput in angular

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am generating pdf using jspdf (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf). I am using doc.output('dataurlnewwindow') to get the pdf in new window. The pdf is generated successfully. But when I click on save from the browser it doesn't do any thing. Only functionality working is print. Also on right click i see save as disabled in the menu.

```
doc.autoTable(col, rows, options); 

if(event.target.innerText == "Open") 
{ 
    doc.output('dataurlnewwindow'); 
} else if(event.target.innerText == "Save As") 
{ 
   doc.autoPrint(); 
   doc.output('dataurlnewwindow'); 
   document.execCommand("SaveAs"); 
} else
{  
   doc.save(this.selectedACH.accountNumber+'.pdf'); 
}
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, please let us to know what is is happening in your code

Comment: Hello! Can you add links/reference to what you are using? jspdf? and add some code to help you. Remove the sentence "Need immediate help." It doesn't add value to your issue

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. Well to sum up i was generating pdf from API data.. the pdf is getting created well. But to auto download the pdf.. I am using doc. save() which is working as expected. I used doc.output('dataurlnewwindow') to open the pdf. The pdf opens well but the save option on the pdf is not working. Also on right click.. the menu shows the save as disabled. So is there other way of opening the PDF?

Comment: @AliBigdeli -     doc.autoTable(col, rows, options);
        if(event.target.innerText == "Open")
        {
          doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
        }
        else if(event.target.innerText == "Save As")
        {
          doc.autoPrint();
          doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
          document.execCommand("SaveAs");
        }
        else{
          doc.save(this.selectedACH.accountNumber+'.pdf');
        }  
I am able to open the pdf, but when the pdf opens the save icon is not working also the save as option on right click is disabled. I am using edge explorer.